# If statement in wp-config.php, is it possible?

Tags: multisite, wp-config

I already searched here and there but couldn't find anything definitive.

I have WordPress multisite and I have a plugin (activated on each site) which requires to set a slug parameter in wp-config.php.

Unfortunately each site of the network requires a different slug parameter.

I'd like to know if it is possible to put an *if statement* in wp-config.php in order to define these parameters based on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable.

Code is the following:

```
if ( stristr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'site.com' ) ) {

    define('ABC_PRODUCT_SLUG', 'slug-for-en');

}
elseif ( stristr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'de.site.com' ) )
{  
    define('ABC_PRODUCT_SLUG', 'slug-for-de');
}
```

Is that **possible and reliable**? Are there any **possible drawbacks**?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is possible and reliable

Comment: a plugin that **requires** wp-config changes? just don't use it. Maybe you should actually ask a question about your problem instead of about the only solution you  see ;) In theory you should do  this can of code in a "must use" plugin. The config file is not something you should modify if you have any alternative as the impact of breaking it during modification is just too big

Comment: Yes, this is possible and perfectly reliable. I have done this for a long time as part of my standard WP install by defining a `SITE_ENVIRONMENT` constant for `local | staging | live` and have variable settings dependent on the environment. Ideally you would define the constant elsewhere (and then include/fetch it) so that you can still push your wp-config between environments without overwriting the environment value. Note: Some hosts - especially dedicated Wordpress managed hosts - don't let you manage wp-config. They always supply workarounds though.

Comment: Note that ` $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is not defined on the command line, e.g. when using WP-CLI.

Comment: Though it's possible and reliable, but just don't do it. Instead, you can create site specific plugins (or for the whole network) and define those constants there.

Comment: @Mark Kaplun, already asked, hopefully they'll solve the issue. And yes, that's a 'must use' plugin of course. BTW what do you mean by 'breaking it during modification'?

Comment: @onebc, could you elaborate on provided suggestion? If applicable to my environment I may accept that as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @Abhik could you elaborate on provided suggestion as well?

Comment: @Antony, when you update your file via (s)FTP a connection error might cause a corruption of the file. As you are unlikely to keep that file in GIT, it is just a risk not worth taking. When in plugin form you can test it on a dev enviroment first and it is easier and safer to deploy and backtrack changes

Comment: @Mark Kaplun, I see the point. So, I seem to understand that the only good alternative to my solution is that the guys who maintain the plugin are willing to customize it in order to solve this. I already asked about that..so finger crossed.

Comment: @Antony, not really, unless it does something even wierder you can do the defines in an MU plugin. But not having a possibility for DB or filter based setting is just bad coding in the context of wordpress. It can make sense in some edge cases, but I yet to see one of those ;)

Comment: Certainly @Antony ... I think it'll be too verbose for a comment so I'll add it as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the comments thread...

Here's a method I've used for a long time for handling the 'not ideal' scenario of different configurations between environments. The following is a heavily cut-down representation of `wp-config.php` but it demonstrates the idea...

```
<?php
  /**
  * The base configurations of the WordPress.
  *
  * This file has the following configurations: MySQL settings, Table Prefix,
  * Secret Keys, WordPress Language, and ABSPATH. You can find more information
  * by visiting {@link http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php Editing
  * wp-config.php} Codex page. You can get the MySQL settings from your web host.
  *
  * This file is used by the wp-config.php creation script during the
  * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can just copy this file
  * to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
  *
  * @package WordPress
*/

/** Environment: LOCAL || STAGING || LIVE **/
define('BCUK_SITE_ENV', 'LOCAL');

/** System/CMS defaults **/
e.g. settings that are common across all environments

if (BCUK_SITE_ENV == "LOCAL"):
e.g. different db settings, memory limits, paths, etc.

elseif (BCUK_SITE_ENV == "STAGING"):
e.g. different db settings, memory limits, paths, etc.

else:
e.g. different db settings, memory limits, paths, etc.

endif;

// Remaining wp-config bits go here e.g. salts, lang settings, etc
```

As you can see I prefer to assume that 'else' means the live settings, just for safety's sake.

I have also used versions of this method where the definition of the environment is actually in a separate file that is included e.g. replacing `define('BCUK_SITE_ENV', 'LOCAL');` with an include statement that pulls in a file (something like 'environment_config.inc.php') in which there is just one line that is used to change the environment constant. That way you can always push your wp-config.php between environments without actually affecting which environment is currently configured.

In all the above, you could easily adapt it to either base your logic directly on the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or to configure your environment variable/constant on the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Hope that all makes sense. It's definitely not the only way, but hopefully it demonstrates that it is definitely a robust and workable method. Whether it works for your particular plugin development scenario only you will know.